# Multiple Identify tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, identify

We currently have two tags, [idenitfy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify) and [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie).  IMHO I think we should make identify-this-movie a synonym of identify.

Comment: Go for it in my opinion.

Comment: What about [tag:identify-this-show]?

Answer (score 4):

On [SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), we have `[story-identification]` regardless of media type (which I is my fault, but [the community is against renaming](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/630/rename-the-story-identification-tag)). I would recommend using `[identify-this-thing]` instead: [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) or [identify-this-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-series). This allows users who specialize in one media type to only follow one of the tags, and users who like all media types can subscribe to `identify-*`. The format is also consistent with [identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/identify-this-game) on [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) (on the other hand, [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) uses [story-identification](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification)).

Answer (score 0):

### **DO IT**

Answer (score 0):

OK, so, TL is saying that instead we should have identify-this-movie and identify-this-tv-show instead of identify....

Comment: I honestly don't mind this, for those identify questions it at least limits the scope of what the item could be to a certain media but would require the asker to actually know at least that much.  For the time being, I tagged the Nickelodeon question with the tv tag and pruged the identify tag.

Comment: I'd like to see what @phwd thought